# R - is.na() within ifelse()

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I am trying to create a new variable `child_or_adult` in my data set `titanic`, by using `mutate()`. The new variable would specify the age group of each person. However, the variable `age` contains `NA`s values, which I don't want to ignore. Instead, I want to classify them as `adult`. How could I do this by using `is.na()` within the `ifeslse()` statement ?

```
titanic %>% 
  mutate(child_or_adult = ifelse(test = age <= 9, 
                                 yes = "child", 
                                 no = "adult", 
                                 is.na(age) <- "adult"
                                 ))
```

Comment: `test = age <= 9 & !is.na(age)`, and remove your `is.na(age)` bit from the end.

Comment: Are your ages integers? You could get away with `ifelse(age %in% 0:9, 'child', 'adult')`

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
 titanic %>% mutate(child_or_adult = ifelse(age <= 9 | !is.na(age),"child","adult"))
```